# Update gensim word2vec model

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I have a word2vec model in gensim trained over 98892 documents. For any given sentence that is not present in the sentences array (i.e. the set over which I trained the model), I need to update the model with that sentence so that querying it next time gives out some results. I am doing it like this:

```
new_sentence = ['moscow', 'weather', 'cold']
model.train(new_sentence)
```

and its printing this as logs:

```
2014-03-01 16:46:58,061 : INFO : training model with 1 workers on 98892 vocabulary and 100 features
2014-03-01 16:46:58,211 : INFO : reached the end of input; waiting to finish 1 outstanding jobs
2014-03-01 16:46:58,235 : INFO : training on 10 words took 0.1s, 174 words/s
```

Now, when I query with similar new_sentence for most positives (as `model.most_similar(positive=new_sentence)`) it gives out error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#220>", line 1, in <module>
 model.most_similar(positive=['moscow', 'weather', 'cold'])
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 405, in most_similar
 raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
  KeyError: "word 'cold' not in vocabulary"
```

Which indicates that the word 'cold' is not part of the vocabulary over which i trained the thing (am I right)?

So the question is: How to update the model so that it gives out all the possible similarities for the given new sentence?

Comment: Someone has updated genism's `Word2Vec` to an `online Word2Vec`. Where you can update your vocabulary list and learn new ones using online learning. I have not tried it though, but check it out at:
http://rutumulkar.com/blog/2015/word2vec/

Answer (score 25):

1. `train()` expects a **sequence** of sentences on input, not **one** sentence.
2. `train()` only [updates weights](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.train) for existing feature vectors based on existing vocabulary. You cannot add new vocabulary (=new feature vectors) using `train()`.

Comment: So how to add new vocabulary? It is definitively not possible? Thank you

Comment: @Nacho, ["The word2vec algorithm doesn’t support adding new words dynamically."](http://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/#comment-2281)  So, no, it isn't possible unless you retrain the entire model with the new vocab.

Comment: WARNING: outdated answer so I'm downvoting this answer to allow the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40936428/1019952 to go up. Or please update your answer.

Answer (score 25):

As of [gensim 0.13.3](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/releases/tag/0.13.3) it's possible to do online training of Word2Vec with gensim.

```
model.build_vocab(new_sentences, update=True)
model.train(new_sentences)
```

Comment: This does not actually work though for some reason.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357678/gensim-word2vec-array-dimensions-in-updating-with-online-word-embedding

Comment: I haven't had issues implementing this. I'll try to take a look at your SO post this weekend.

Comment: @chase I answered your SO post

Answer (score 8):

If your model was generated using the C tool load_word2vec_format it is not possible to update that model. See the word2vec tutorial section on Online Training [Word2Vec Tutorial](http://radimrehurek.com/2014/02/word2vec-tutorial/):

> Note that it’s not possible to resume training with models generated
>   by the C tool, load_word2vec_format(). You can still use them for
>   querying/similarity, but information vital for training (the vocab
>   tree) is missing there.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot add new words to a pre-trained model's.

However, there's a "new" doc2vec model published in 2014 which meets all your requirement. You can use it to train a document vector instead of getting a set of word vector then combine them.
The best part is doc2vec can infer unseen sentences after training. Although the model is still unchangable, you can get a pretty good inference result based on my experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you can not retrain word2vec model with new Sentences. Only doc2vec allows it. Try doc2vec model.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the model vocabulary, and add to the embedding using [FastText](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html).

```py
from gensim.models import FastText
```

[Here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/FastText_Tutorial.ipynb) you can see some FastText examples. [Here](https://github.com/shabeelkandi/Handling-Out-of-Vocabulary-Words-in-Natural-Language-Processing-using-Language-Modelling/blob/master/Fasttext%20Model.ipynb) you can see how to use FastText to score Out-of-vocabulary (OOV) instances.